# Let $f,g: X \rightarrow Y$ be continuous and $Y$ be Hausdorff. Prove that $\{x | f(x) = g(x)\}$ is a closed subset of $X$.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

I realize this question has been asked, But i just wrote up this proof and it's a little different so I was hoping somebody would check it.

Let $f,g: X \rightarrow Y$ be continuous and $Y$ be Hausdorff. Prove that $Z=\{x | f(x) = g(x)\}$ is a closed subset of $X$.

Proof: Let $x \in X-Z$

Then $f(x) \neq g(x)$, and since $Y$ is hausdorff this implies that  $\exists U_1, U_2$ open in $Y$ s.t. $f(x) \in U_1$, $g(x) \in U_2$ and $U_1 \cap U_2 = \emptyset$.

Since $f$ is continuous and $U_1$ is open in $Y$, we have $f^{-1}(U_1)$ is open in $X$ and $x \in f^{-1}(U_1)$.

Since $g$ is continuous and $U_2$ is open in $Y$, we have $g^{-1}(U_2)$ is open in $X$ and $x \in g^{-1}(U_2)$.

Claim: $g^{-1}(U_2) \cap f^{-1}(U_1)$ is a neighborhood of $x$ contained in $X-Z$.

Suppose $z \in  g^{-1}(U_2) \cap f^{-1}(U_1)$, then $f(z) \in U_1$, $g(z) \in U_2$. But $U_1 \cap U_2 = \emptyset$ and so $f(z) \neq g(z)$ and thus $z \in X-Z$.

Thus $X-Z$ is open and thus $Z$ is closed

Comment: Seems to be a correct proof

Comment: Perfectly right. A useful corollary is that if $Y$ is Hausdorff and $f:X\to Y,\,g:X\to Y$ are continuous and agree on a dense subset of $X$ then $f=g.$ For example, in the proof of the Jones Lemma.

Answer (score 1):

The proof you have given is correct, but the identical proof has been given on this site too. E.g. [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3177682/4280) is very close. Or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2469559/4280). Or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/465563/4280). It's the most "obvious" proof.